# Error in RipUvK CTFS Package

Tags: r

Intento calcular "Ripley's index (spatial point pattern) for a species group", pero cuando uso la función justo como recomienda el sitio oficial, me sale un error.

```r
RipUvK=function(splitdata,plotdim=c(1000,500),rseq=c(5,10,20,30,40,50),mindbh=10,xcol="gx",ycol="gy",debug=FALSE,show=FALSE)
    {
      spp.names <- names(splitdata)
      plotarea=plotdim[1]*plotdim[2]/1e4

      omega=matrix(nrow=length(spp.names),ncol=length(rseq))
      rip.list=Ovalue=list()
      abund=numeric()

      poly=spoints(c(0,0,plotdim[1],0,plotdim[1],plotdim[2],0,plotdim[2]))
    }
```

Uso la función RipUvK así:

```r
    RipUvK(data2, plotdim = c(500,500), rseq = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,50), mindbh = 10, 
           xcol = "gx", ycol = "gy", debug = FALSE, show = FALSE)
```

(data2 es un objeto de tipo "splitdata" con las especies del bosque, y plotdim es el tamaño de la parcela, 500 m x 500 m)

Me sale este error:

```
Error in spoints(c(0, 0, plotdim[1], 0, plotdim[1], plotdim[2], 0, plotdim[2])) : 
  could not find function "spoints"
```

No sé si "spoints" pertenece a otro paquete. Si es así, no se qué será. Qué significa este error?

**Postdata: Soy principante**

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estas en SO en español, en caso contrario podría terminar cerrada

Answer (score 0):

Consultando en la documentación del paquete "ctfs" en [Github](https://github.com/forestgeo/ctfs/blob/master/R/RipUvK.R) veo que `spoints()` es una función del paquete "splancs", disponible en CRAN. Prueba instalarlo (no es necesario llamarlo con `library()`) antes de correr `RipUvK()`.